# How to filter a template tag?

Tags: django, django-templates

I've got a tag that looks like this:

```
{% partial "partials/vehicleform.html" vehicle=vehicles.empty_form %}
```

Which just renders an empty form. But now I want to pass the output of that to the `escapejs` filter so that I can use it in a JavaScript variable. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Applying a filter to the output of a template tag can also be accomplished without any external dependencies using the built in `filter` template tag. From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#filter):

> [This template tag] filters the contents of the block through one or more filters. Multiple filters can be specified with pipes and filters can have arguments, just as in variable syntax.

The example in the original question would be written like this:

```
{% filter escapejs %}
{% partial "partials/vehicleform.html" vehicle=vehicles.empty_form %}
{% endfilter %}
```

Comment: This filter approach is useful, but be aware that the block content will be coerced to a string before applying the filter. That means filters that work on non-string types like `date` or `json_script` won't work. In that case, the `as myvar` approach may be more appropriate.

Answer (score 15):

Many tags support `as variablename` -- that is, simple put `as variablename` at the end of the tag and then the output of that tag is placed in the variable rather than displayed.

This `{% partial %}` tag may support that. Here's an example, if it does:

```
{% partial "partials/vehicleform.html" vehicle=vehicles.empty_form as myvar %}{{ myvar|escapejs }}
```

If the tag in question is the ["Partial tag" snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1544/) then it appears it doesn't support this. But it probably could be rewritten to support it.

You could use the "[Capture template output as a variable](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/545/)" snippet, and then apply the filter to the captured content, like so:

```
{% captureas myvar %}{% partial "partials/vehicleform.html" vehicle=vehicles.empty_form  %}{% endcaptureas %}{{ myvar|escapejs }}
```

Comment: It's a modified version of the partial tag snippet that supports variable naming. http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2104/ I think the `captureas` sol'n should work.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution to get the data into a JS variable:

```
<div class="display:none" id="empty-vehicle-form">{% partial "partials/vehicleform.html" vehicle=vehicles.empty_form %}</div>
```

Then nab it and remove it at the same time

```
var empty_form = $('#empty-vehicle-form').remove().html();
```

The advantage of this solution is that your other JS scripts can preprocess it before you rip it out of the DOM. `escapejs` also creates bigger filesizes with all those escape chars.